# Stuck between Selected with .JS .filters/.map

Tags: javascript

So I got this segment of code, whenever someone has the highest selected they are meant to be removed from the query, as you can see from the snippet it works normal, 4 is caught and removed as supposed to.

```js
const result_arr = [
  {selected: 3, absent: 0},
  {selected: 4, absent: 0},
  {selected: 2, absent: 0},
]

const max = Math.max(
  ...result_arr.filter(item => !item.absent).map(item => item.selected)
);
console.log(max);
  
let newArr = result_arr.filter(item => item.selected != max).filter(item => !item.absent);
console.log(newArr);
```

I'm running into an issue seen in the snippet below. Whenever one of the Selected hit equal numbers, which will most definitely occur, it returns an empty array.

```js
const result_arr = [
  {selected: 4, absent: 0},
  {selected: 4, absent: 0},
  {selected: 4, absent: 0},
]

const max = Math.max(
  ...result_arr.filter(item => !item.absent).map(item => item.selected)
);
console.log(max);
  
let newArr = result_arr.filter(item => item.selected != max).filter(item => !item.absent);
console.log(newArr);
```

What I want instead is for all 3 to be returned and used, as seen in the snippet below.

```js
const result_arr = [
  {selected: 4, absent: 0},
  {selected: 4, absent: 0},
  {selected: 4, absent: 0},
]

const max = Math.max(
  ...result_arr.filter(item => !item.absent).map(item => item.selected)
);
console.log(max);
  
let newArr = result_arr.filter(item => item.selected == max).filter(item => !item.absent);
console.log(newArr);
```

I changed != to ==, so I'm wary of how to do this but how do I compile this into one? Will an If else work, I already tried one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial code seems too complicated for your requirements.

1. Get an array of selected values.
2. Get the `max` of those values.
3. If [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) value in the selected array is `max` return the whole array, otherwise return the filtered array.

```js
const arr=[{selected:3,absent:0},{selected:4,absent:0},{selected:2,absent:0}];
const arr2=[{selected:4,absent:0},{selected:4,absent:0},{selected:4,absent:0}];
const arr3=[{selected:4,absent:0},{selected:2,absent:0},{selected:4,absent:0}];

function check(arr) {

  const selected = arr.map(obj => obj.selected);

  const max = Math.max(...selected);

  if (selected.every(el => el === max)) {
    return arr;
  }

  return arr.filter(item => item.selected !== max)

}

console.log(check(arr));
console.log(check(arr2));
console.log(check(arr3));
```